# Maximum simultaneous connection when using ftp adapter

Tags: ftp, spring-integration

What can I tweak to solve this maximum connection problem? Any ways to specify a limit?
This is from a Spring Integration application.

```
 <int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="matasLiveProdSdkOutbound"
                                      channel="ftpOutboundChannel"
                                      session-factory="ftpsSessionFactory"
                                      charset="UTF-8"
                                      auto-create-directory="true"
                                      use-temporary-file-name="false"
                                      remote-file-separator="/"
                                      remote-directory-expression="${egnyte.remote.dir}"
                                      mode="IGNORE">
</int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

This is the error I get:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to execute on session; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create FTPClient
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:343)
    at org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.FtpRemoteFileTemplate.doExecuteWithClient(FtpRemoteFileTemplate.java:51)
    at org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.FtpRemoteFileTemplate.executeWithClient(FtpRemoteFileTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.FtpRemoteFileTemplate.exists(FtpRemoteFileTemplate.java:62)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.sendFileToRemoteDirectory(RemoteFileTemplate.java:435)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create FTPClient
    at org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.AbstractFtpSessionFactory.getSession(AbstractFtpSessionFactory.java:171)
    at org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.AbstractFtpSessionFactory.getSession(AbstractFtpSessionFactory.java:41)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:332)
    ... 74 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: 550 Cannot connect. You have reached maximum allowed simultaneous connections 7 per user.
```

**Edit:** Adding a CachingSessionFactory, like Gary advised me to...

```
@Bean
    public CachingSessionFactory ftpsCachingSessionFactory(DefaultFtpsSessionFactory ftpsSessionFactory) {
        CachingSessionFactory cachingSessionFactory = new CachingSessionFactory(ftpsSessionFactory, 5);
        cachingSessionFactory.setSessionWaitTimeout(1000);
        return cachingSessionFactory;
    }
```

I've wrapped the ftps session factory in a cachingSessionFactoy. Now, when I refer to this bean from the ftp outbound adapter above, I get an error telling me that the bean must be of type *AbstractFtpSessionFactory*. Is using an **FTPS** caching session factory not possible in an FTP outbound adapter - like the one above? I can't find any int-ftps namespace to switch the adapter with. The spring-integration-ftp-4.1xsd expectedly states that only a *org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpSessionFactory* is accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the session factory in a `CachingSessionFactory`. Use [this constructor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-file/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/file/remote/session/CachingSessionFactory.java#L71) which allows you to limit the number of sessions.

Also see [setSessionWaitTimeout](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-file/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/file/remote/session/CachingSessionFactory.java#L99).

Comment: of course... how did I miss that!? Thanks. I now experience a type mismatch when trying to use my cachingSessionFactory with my ftp-outbound-channel-adapter. See my edited question. isn't it possible to solve this out-of-the-box?

Comment: Well, i ignored the error and it acctually is working. My guess is that the xsd is not complete and only defines Reference to a [org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory] bean. as an expected type (?)

Comment: Oh, you mean a schema validation error in the IDE. As you have found, this is not a runtime error, it's just a (wrong) hint to the IDE, which can be ignored. I have opened a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3735) to fix this. Configuring the cache this way was changed in 2011, so I'm a bit surprised nobody reported this before. Thanks!